# Most hat-tricks in a single gameweek

Tags: football, trivia, english-premier-league

During Gameweek 4 of the 2023/4 Premier League season, there were 3 separate hat-trick scorers:

- Son Heung-Min (Burnley vs **Tottenham Hotspur**)
- Erling Haaland (**Manchester City** vs Fulham)
- Evan Ferguson (**Brighton** vs Newcastle)

Hat-tricks are fairly rare - there are usually [somewhere between 10-20 per season in the Premier League](https://footballcollective.org.uk/terminology/hat-trick/) - so to have 3 in a single gameweek is very unusual.

**What is the most amount of separate hat-trick scorers in a single gameweek in the Premier League (and the old First Division)?**

Comment: Is this meant as a question specifically about EPL? (In that case the tag ([tag:english-premier-league]) would be suitable.) Or is the question supposed to be general about the top leagues in Europe?

Comment: Several leagues have [list of hat-tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_association_football_team_hat-tricks) on Wikipedia - for example, [Premier League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Premier_League_hat-tricks) or [Bundesliga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bundesliga_hat-tricks). 
One could go through those list to see whether there are hat-tricks with dates close to each other. (But this approach is rather time consuming.)

Comment: BTW in the list for Bundesliga one can see at the beginning a single match with three hat tricks - Borussia Mönchengladbach - Schalke 11:0 (Jupp Heynckes, Herbert Laumen and Bernd Rupp).

Comment: This very question came up during BBC Sport's live feed, and someone pointed to a Premier League game week in 1995 where there were three hat-tricks. I suspect that if you go back to the Division One era, when matches tended to be higher-scoring, that's where the record will be.

Answer (score 2):

Sticking with just the Premier League, there have been five other game weeks in which three hat-tricks were scored:

- 23 September 1995, when Robbie Fowler (Liverpool), Alan Shearer (Blackburn), and Tony Yeboah (Leeds Utd) scored hat-tricks
- 27-28 September 2003, when Ruud van Nistelrooy (Man Utd), Kevin Lisbie (Charlton), and Steve Watson (Everton) scored hat-tricks
- 25-26 October 2019, when Jamie Vardy, Ayoze Pérez (both Leicester), and Christian Pulisic (Chelsea) scored hat-tricks
- 23-24 October 2021, when Mason Mount (Chelsea), Joshua King (Watford), and Mohamed Salah (Liverpool) scored hat-tricks
- 1-2 October 2022, when Erling Haaland, Phil Foden (both Man City), and Leandro Trossard (Brighton) scored hat-tricks.

Fascinating that they all occurred in September or October...

I suspect that if you go back to the Division One era, when matches tended to be higher-scoring, you'll find game weeks with larger numbers of hat-tricks, but there don't seem to be any convenient resources for finding hat-tricks scored during that era.